# Increase load speed

Tags: cognito-forms

It takes a couple of seconds for the form to load which blocks the rest of the page from loading.

Are there recommendations on how to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) loads asynchronously and should not block the rest of your page from loading.  However, the loading performance is affected by the complexity of the page it is embedded in, as well as the complexity of the form itself.

If possible, please include a link to the page your form is embedded in and we will take a look to see if these is anything that can be done to optimize the loading performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jamie. Can I email you the link?

Comment: Since you are a Cognito Forms user, just submit a bug report on our support page and we'll take it from there.